# How can I enable history for the Run dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

As an administrator on Windows Vista, when I do Start -> Run, there is no history of the commands I typed previously (MRU).

I suppose it's disabled for administrators because of security reasons but it's also very annoying. Can it be enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on taskbar, go to Properties, Start Menu - check "Store and display a list of recently opened programs" under privacy.  This should enable the MRU history.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely to appear due to the fact that a user has *intentionally* ***un***checked the option to show recently opened programs in the start menu.

The user might only want pinned items to show in the start menu. The solution presented might change that behaviour.

In order to prevent recent items to show **and** getting the run window history you need to set the "Number of recent programs to display" to zero.

[image]

I know this was not explicitly asked in the question, but I think this is a relevant addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 the following link was very useful:
https://winaero.com/blog/fix-run-does-not-save-command-history-in-windows-10/

- Open Settings
- Go to System -> Personalization -> Start.
- On the right, turn on the option **Show most used apps**

If **Show most used apps** is grayed out.

- Open Settings
- Go to Privacy -> General
- Turn on **Let Windows track app launches to improve Start and search results**

No go back to the original steps. The **Show most used apps** should be available now.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski shot for the tip, have updated my answer