# How to enable command history in Run command dialog box?

Tags: windows-7, command-history, run-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable history for Run dialog for Vista administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/25265/enable-history-for-run-dialog-for-vista-administrator)

In my PC (running Windows 7 Professional - 64 bit), the Run dialog box does not keep the history of previous commands! So no suggestions are shown when a command is entered! 
 How do I enable this?

[image: No suggestions are shown as I type a command!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Right-click on the taskbar.
2. Click on Properties.
3. Click on the Start Menu Button.
4. Check the

> Store and display a list of recently opened programs

option under privacy.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Worked fine for the command line history issue. Thanks.  ** But now the start menu has started keeping a hisotry of recently used programs which I **don't like**.  (?) How can I keep the history for commands in 'Run' box only, without keeping the recently opened programs history in the start menu?

Comment: Confirmed to work in Windows 10, but under a different location. Settings > Personalization > Start > Show most used apps

Comment: Solution to your question, @CRoshanLG: You can go to "adjust" in the same tab (or "customize" or "advanced", don't know, my Windows sadly is German and I can't change it) and set the number of programs to show there to 0. That effectively disables the list in the start menu, but the history in "Run" is still the maximum.

Comment: in win10:  "Go to Settings>Privacy>General and turn ON "Let Windows track app launches...."  https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/81608-show-most-used-apps-toggle-settings-greyed-out.html