# How to enable command history in Run, without enabling recently opened programs history in start menu?

Tags: windows-7, command-history, run-dialog

I want to enable command history in Run dialog box, without enabling recently opened programs history in start menu?

(!) [This](https://superuser.com/questions/25265/how-can-i-enable-history-for-the-run-dialog) previous answer will enable history in **both** Run **and** Start Menu (recently opened programs), which I don't want to enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the answer you linked to:

```
Right-click on taskbar
Go to Properties, Start Menu
Check "Store and display a list of recently opened programs" under privacy.
```

But then afterwards do this:

```
Open the registry editor (Start -> Run -> regedit)
Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
Add a key or amend the value for the following: 

 NoRecentDocsMenu      1
 NoRecentDocsHistory   1
```